# A tricky integral involving hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Can anyone suggest a method for solving the integral below? I've tried numerous things but have had no luck yet. To be honest I'm not sure an analytical solution actually exists.

$$I=\int\cosh(2x)\sqrt{[\sinh(x)]^{-2/3}+[\cosh(x)]^{-2/3}}\,\textrm{d}x.$$

Thanks.

Here is another attempt I have made:

Let $y=[\tanh(x)]^{2/3}$, and rewrite $I$ such that

$$I=\int\cosh(2x)[\sinh(x)]^{-1/3}\sqrt{1+[\tanh(x)]^{2/3}}\,\textrm{d}x.$$

Then $\textrm{d}x=(3/2)[\tanh(x)]^{1/3}[\cosh(x)]^{2}\,\textrm{d}y$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{3}{2}\int\cosh(2x)[\sinh(x)]^{-1/3}[\tanh(x)]^{1/3}[\cosh(x)]^{2}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int\cosh(2x)[\cosh(x)]^{5/3}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int[\cosh(x)]^{11/3}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
+\frac{3}{2}\int[\sinh(x)]^{2}[\cosh(x)]^{5/3}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int[\textrm{sech}(x)]^{-11/3}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
+\frac{3}{2}\int[\tanh(x)]^{2}[\textrm{sech}(x)]^{-11/3}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int[\textrm{sech}(x)]^{-11/3}\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
+\frac{3}{2}\int[\textrm{sech}(x)]^{-11/3}y^3\sqrt{1+y}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{(1+y)^{1/2}}{(1-y^3)^{11/6}}\,\textrm{d}y
+\frac{3}{2}\int y^{3}\frac{(1+y)^{1/2}}{(1-y^3)^{11/6}}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{(1+y^3)(1+y)^{1/2}}{(1-y^3)^{11/6}}\,\textrm{d}y
\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{(1-y^6)(1+y)^{1/2}}{(1-y^3)^{17/6}}\,\textrm{d}y
\end{align*}

Comment: It would be really great if you showed us what you've done even if it hasn't worked :)

Comment: Have edited my original post.

Comment: Thank you! You have earned an upvote from me :)

Comment: Nice work for sure and $\to +1$

Comment: I wouldn't be optimistic: WolframAlpha seems to fail.

Comment: Where is this problem from? It looks very tough.

Comment: Hard and nice integral, with the close form expressed via high special functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Version of 03.05.19}}$

Are known the identities

> $$\begin{cases}
> \cosh^2t-\sinh^2t = 1\\
> 2\cosh^2t = \cosh2t + 1\\
> 2\sinh^2t = \cosh2t -1\\
> 2\sinh t\cosh t = \sinh 2t\\
> \cosh^{-2}t = 1-\tanh^2x\\
> \sinh^{-2}t = \coth^2x-1\\
> (\tanh x)' = \cosh^{-2}t\\
> (\coth x)' = -\sinh^{-2}t.
> \end{cases}\tag1$$

One can get

$$\cosh^{\large^-\frac23}x + \sinh^{\large-^\frac23}x
 = \sqrt[{\large3}]{1-\tanh^2x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth^2x-1},$$
$$\cosh^{\large^-\frac23}x + \sinh^{\large-^\frac23}x
 = \sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x - \tanh x}
(\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}),\tag2$$
$$\cosh2x = \dfrac{\cosh^2x+\sinh^2x}{\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x}
=\dfrac{\coth x + \tanh x}{\cot x - \tanh x}.\tag3$$
Therefore,
$$I = \int\cosh2x\sqrt{\cosh^{\large^-\frac23}x + \sinh^{\large^-\frac23}x\,}\,dx,$$
$$I = \int\dfrac{\coth x + \tanh x}{(\coth x - \tanh x)^{\large^\frac56}} \sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}\,dx.\tag4$$

Taking in account that
$$\left(\frac65(\sinh x \cosh x)^{\large^-\frac56}\right)'
= \dfrac{\coth x + \tanh x}{(\coth x - \tanh x)^{\large\frac56}}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(d%2Fdx%20(sinh%20x%20cosh%20x)%5E(5%2F6)%20)%20-5%2F6%20(coth%20x%20%2B%20tanh%20x)%2F(coth%20x%20-%20tanh%20x)%5E(5%2F6))),
$$\left(\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}\right)'
= \dfrac{\left(\coth^{\large^-\frac23}x (1-\coth^2x)
+ \tanh^{\large^-\frac23}x (1-\tanh^2x)\right)}{6\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}}$$
$$= -\dfrac{(\coth x - \tanh x) 
\left(\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} - \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}\right)}{6\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}},$$

is possible the integration by parts:
$$I(x) = -\dfrac65 \int\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}\,\mathrm d\left((\sinh x \cosh x)^{\large^-\frac56}\right),$$
$$I(x) = \dfrac35 I_1(x) - \dfrac65\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}\,(\sinh x \cosh x)^{\large^-\frac56},\tag5$$
where
$$I_1(x) = \int \left((\sinh x \cosh x)^{\large^-\frac56}\right) \dfrac{\mathrm d\left(\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}}.
\tag6$$
Let
$$\left(\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} - \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}\right)^2 = y,\tag7$$
then
$$\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x} 
= \sqrt{y+4}\,$$
$$(\sinh x \cosh x)^{-1} = \dfrac{\cosh^2x - \sinh^2x}{\sinh x \cosh x} = \coth x - \tanh x = \sqrt y (y+3),$$
$$I(x) = \dfrac3{10} J\left(\left(\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} - \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}\right)^2\right) - \dfrac65\sqrt{\sqrt[{\large3}]{\coth x} + \sqrt[{\large3}]{\tanh x}}\,(\sinh x \cosh x)^{\large^-\frac56},\tag8$$
where
$$J(y) = \int (y+3)^{\large^\frac56}(y+4)^{\large^-\frac34}\,y^{\large^\frac5{12}}\,dy\tag9,$$

wherein the last integral can be expressed [in the closed form of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(z%2B3)%5E(5%2F6)+(z%2B1)%5E(-3%2F4)+z%5E(5%2F12)+dz)
$$\begin{align}
&J(y) = \frac2{51} y^{\large^\frac5{12}} \left(-17\cdot 3^{\large^\frac56} F_1\left(\frac5{12}; \frac34, \frac16; \frac{17}{12};-y, -\frac y3\right)\right.\\
& + \left. 5\cdot 3^{\large^\frac56} y F_1\left(\frac{17}{12}; \frac34, \frac16;\frac{29}{12}; -y, -\frac y3\right) + 17 (y+1)^{\large^\frac14} (y+3)^{\large^\frac56}\right) + \mathrm{constant}
\end{align}\tag{10}$$
via the [Appell hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html) of two variables.

Formulas $(8),(10)$ $\color{brown}{\textbf{present the given integral in the closed form}}.$

Comment: The first identity you state doesn't seem to be correct. If I set $u^3-v^3=1$ then $4(\frac{u-v}{2})^3+3\frac{u-v}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(u-v)(1-uv)$ which I cannot seem to reduce further unless $uv=1$. Can you provide a proof of the statement?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Thanks! The new version proposed.

Comment: Alpha not finding a solution is a good indication that no closed-form exists.

Comment: In the steps below (3) and above (4) there should be a $$\sqrt[3]{\sinh(2x)}=\sqrt[6]{y^2-1}$$ in the denominator.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. In fact, according to my working, using the substitution proposed I obtain

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{y+1}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{y-1}{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{y^2-1}{2}}}\right)^{1/2}\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^{2}-1}}\,\textrm{d}y.$$

Nothing more manageable!

Comment: @Diger Thanks! Generally fixed.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Generally fixed.

Comment: @Juggler Thanks for the support, generally fixed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think that we have exception, due to the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

Comment: When starting with (6), possibly in expression (8) $y^{-1/6}$ should be $y^{5/12}/2$ ?

Comment: @Diger Of course. Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: definitely hard, and definitely interesting !

Comment: @GCab [Crazy integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739358/nested-root-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx/3311446#3311446)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov:  your imagination + expertise is really admirable.

Comment: @GCab [Nice substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578605/integral-int-0-infty-frac-ln-left-sqrtx1-vphantomx0-1-right-ln-lef/3489521#3489521)

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer:**

Integration by parts with $$\sf{f(y)=\frac{1-y^6}{(1-y^3)^{17/6}}\implies f'(y)=\frac{y^2(17+5y^3)}{2(1-y^3)^{17/6}}}\\ g'(y)=(1+y)^{1/2}\implies g(y)=\frac23(1+y)^{3/2}$$ gives $$\sf{J=\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{(1-y^6)(1+y)^{1/2}}{(1-y^3)^{17/6}}\,dy=\frac{(1-y^6)(1+y)^{3/2}}{(1-y^3)^{17/6}}-\overbrace{\frac12\int\frac{y^2(1+y)^{3/2}}{(1-y^3)^{17/6}}(17+5y^3)\,dy}^K}$$ and the substitution $\sf{w=1-y^3}$ yields $$\small\sf{K=-\frac16\int\frac{(1+\sqrt[3]{1-w})^{3/2}}{w^{17/6}}(22-5w)\,dw=\overbrace{\frac56\int\frac{(1+\sqrt[3]{1-w})^{3/2}}{w^{11/6}}\,dw}^P-\overbrace{\frac{11}3\int\frac{(1+\sqrt[3]{1-w})^{3/2}}{w^{17/6}}\,dw}^Q}.$$ It is possible to simplify further; let us consider $\sf Q$ first. Integration by parts again with \begin{align}\sf{f(w)=(1+(1-w)^{1/3})^{3/2}}&\sf{\implies f'(w)=-\frac{(1+(1-w)^{1/3})^{1/2}}{2(1-w)^{2/3}}}\\\sf{g'(w)=\frac1{w^{17/6}}}&\sf{\implies g(w)=-\frac6{11w^{11/6}}}\end{align} gives $$\sf{Q=\frac{11}3\left[-\frac{6(1+\sqrt[3]{1-w})^{3/2}}{11w^{11/6}}-\frac3{11}\int\frac{(1+(1-w)^{1/3})^{1/2}}{w^{11/6}(1-w)^{2/3}}\,dw\right]}$$ and the substitution $\sf{t=1+(1-w)^{1/3}}$ yields $$\sf{Q=-\frac{2(1+\sqrt[3]{1-w})^{3/2}}{w^{11/6}}+3\int\frac{\sqrt t}{(1-(t-1)^3)^{11/6}}\,dt}$$ and since $\sf{1-(t-1)^3=(2-t)(t^2-t+1)}$, the substitution $\sf{s=2-t}$ results in $$\sf{\int\frac{\sqrt t}{(1-(t-1)^3)^{11/6}}\,dt=\int\frac{\sqrt{2-s}}{s^{11/6}(s^2-3s+3)^{11/6}}\,ds.}$$ Using a similar procedure, we find that $$\sf{P=-\frac{(1+\sqrt[3]{1-w})^{3/2}}{w^{5/6}}+\frac32\int\frac{\sqrt{2-s}}{s^{5/6}(s^2-3s+3)^{5/6}}\,ds}$$ and putting back $\sf{w=1-y^3}$, we can now derive a simpler expression for $\sf J$: $$\sf{J=\frac{(1-y^6)[(1+y)^{3/2}-y^{3/2}]}{(1-y^3)^{17/6}}+3\int\frac{\sqrt{2-s}}{s^{11/6}(s^2-3s+3)^{11/6}}\,ds-\frac32\int\frac{\sqrt{2-s}}{s^{5/6}(s^2-3s+3)^{5/6}}\,ds}.$$

Comment: That font looks sweet, by the way! :P

Answer (score 0):

**Other attempt:**

With $t=e^{2x}$, and omitting a constant factor, you obtain the rational form

$$\int (t+t^{-1})\sqrt{(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})^{-2/3}+(t^{1/2}+t^{-1/2})^{-2/3}}\frac{dt}t$$

or

$$\int (t^2+1)(t^2-1)^{-1/3}\sqrt{(t-1)^{2/3}+(t+1)^{2/3}}\,t^{-4/3}\,dt.$$

Nothing more appetizing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yuri for his working. Very helpful. I believe I have arrived at the solution now

\begin{align*}
 I&=\int\cosh(2x)\sqrt{[\sinh(x)]^{-2/3}+[\cosh(x)]^{-2/3}}\,\textrm{d}x
\\
&=\int\cosh(2x)\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{-1/6}[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}\,\textrm{d}x
 \\
 &=\frac{6}{5}\int\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{5/6}
 [\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}\,\textrm{d}x
 \\
 &=\frac{6}{5}\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{5/6}[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}
 \\&\quad-\frac{6}{5}
 \int\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{5/6}\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}\,\textrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now

\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}
 =\frac{1}{6}\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{-1}\frac{[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}-\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]}{[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
 I_{2}&=\frac{6}{5}
 \int\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{5/6}\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}\,\textrm{d}x
\\&=
 \frac{1}{5}\int\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{-1/6}
 \frac{[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}-\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]}{[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}}\,\textrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Let $y=[\sqrt[3]{\tanh(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\coth(x)}]^{1/2}$ then

\begin{equation*}
 I_{2}=
 \frac{6}{5}\int\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{5/6}\,\textrm{d}y=\frac{6}{5}\int[\coth(x)-\tanh(x)]^{-5/6}\,\textrm{d}y
.
\end{equation*}

After a bit of work it is possible to show that

\begin{equation*}
\coth(x)-\tanh(x)=(y^{4}-1)\sqrt{y^{4}-4}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore

$$I=\frac{6}{5}\biggl\{\biggl[\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}\biggr]^{5/6}y-\int(y^{4}-1)^{-5/6}(y^{4}-4)^{-5/12}\,\textrm{d}y\biggr\},$$

where $y$ is as above and the integral can be written in terms of the [hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(y%5E4-1)%5E(-5%2F6)*(y%5E4-4)%5E(-5%2F12)).

A very interesting problem!
Thanks to all.